# Asset rake tasks not available on Rails 3.1 app in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

When I run "bundle exec rake -T" in development, the assets:clear and assets:precompile tasks show up, but if I prefix that command with RAILS_ENV=production, or run it on a server where that variable is set, they don't.  Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd removed rails/all from the application.rb and replaced it with the individual railties, excluding activerecord.  Turns out you also need to require the sprockets railtie.